# Add animation to change focus using tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm going to create scrolling page with many inputs (some wizard). I need some CSS trick to animate scrolling (something like transition, but transition doesn't work) when user press Tab key. As we know it changes focus to next element and scrolls if needed. It works perfectly but I want to add animation. Now it jumps as you can see below. Is it possible?

```css
.foo {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul style="height:70px; overflow:auto">
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>

</ul>
```

More info:

I know solutions with animate js, transitions etc.. But it's not animation when you use tab key still.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, your demo is not very clear what you want exactly ? I wanna suggest https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ but I am unsure what you want. there maybe a lot of ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you need something like this..

```css
.foo {
  height: 50px;
}

input[type=text], textarea {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
 
input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```

```html
<ul style="height:70px; overflow:auto">
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="foo">
    <input type="text">
  </li>

</ul>
```

Please check below link for more information

[Glowing blue input highlights](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/glowing-blue-input-highlights/)

Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: Please add at least some information from the link to your answer, in case the original URL doesn't stand the test of time.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work when you use tab key (Chrome, macOS).